# ¿Cómo pasar punteros de estructuras como argumento en c#?

Tags: c#, punteros, clase, estructuras

Ocurre una cosa que no me esperaba en C# cuando paso como argumneto un una estructura como párametro. Me explico con ejemplos que es mas fácil de ver.

Tengo esta structura:

```
public struct Test
{
    public bool var;
}
```

Tengo esta clase:

```
public calss MiClase
{
    Test t;

    public MiClase()
    {
       t.var=true;
    }
}
```

Y tengo esta otra clase:

```
public calss MiOtraClase
{
    Test t;

    public MiClase(MiClase mc)
    {
       t.var = mc.t.var;   // no pasa el valor de "var"
       Debug.Log(t.var);  // --> **Imprime FALSE**
    }
}
```

Ocurre exactamente lo mismo si en MiClase instancio "t" de esta forma:

```
public calss MiClase
{
    Test t;

    public MiClase()
    {
       t = new Test();
       t.var=true;
    }
}
```

Pero sin embargo si en vez declarar "Test" como una **estructura** lo declaro como una **clase** ocurre algo muy diferente. En el siguiente caso se comporta como si hubiése pasado un **puntero como parámetro** (que es lo que me interesa que ocurra).

```
public class Test
{
    public bool var;
}

public calss MiClase
{
    Test t;

    public MiClase()
    {
       t = new Test();
       t.var=true;
    }
}

public calss MiOtraClase
{
    Test t;

    public MiClase(MiClase mc)
    {
       t.var = mc.t.var;   // si pasa el valor de "var"
       Debug.Log(t.var);  // --> **Imprime TRUE**
    }
}
```

Ahora que sé como funciona esto, el problema se presenta cuando quiero pasar un puntero de una estructura predefinida (que no he creado yo) y que no puedo convertir en una clase como parámetro.

¿Existe alguna forma de poder hacer eso? Es decir, pasar un puntero a una estructura como parámetro.
Gracias!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

para pasar un parámetro de tipo valor por referencia se usa **ref**, en la declaración del método y al invocarlo

```
public void Toquetea(ref int valor){
       valor += 10;
}

//
int cosa = 0;
Toquetea(ref cosa);
```

(struct es un tipo por valor, igual que los primitivos como int, https://docs.microsoft.com/es-ES/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/builtin-types/value-types)

Comment: Muchas Gracias!!

Comment: Y en el caso de que ese dato esté dentro de un objeto? Como en el ejemplo que está declarado dentro de una clase...

Answer (score 0):

Te recomiendo mejor utilizar la clase misma como parámetro, aunque tengas tu struct, utilízala como molde de datos, no mandes un atributo de un objeto para modificarse por referencia ya que va llegar un punto donde vas a perder el rastreo de quienes modifican el estado.

Comment: Gracias Héctor!! precisamente llevo toda la tarde peleandome con ese tema!! Y ahora tengo otro problema muy parecido... no se si crear otra pregunta con ese tema... es exactamente lo miso pero en vez de pasar como párametro  (MiClase mc) estoy pasando el puntero "this"... y me acabo de enterar de que es de solo lectura... y necesito modificar algunos miembros de la clase.... Que lio... el C# este está demasiado capado... como hecho de menos poder usar punteros de toda la vida sin limitaciones... :-(

Comment: Acompaña con codigo la respuesta Hector, para que sea de facil comprension.

Comment: Vale... solucioné lo del "this" y sin usar lo de "ref"... no como a mi me hubiera guastado pero al menos funciona.... creo que al final voy a abrir otra hilo a ver si alguien sabe hacerlo como yo quiero...